# Site is showing differently in browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I have a project where we are to create a portfolio of our work.
But there is the problem:

If you look at [my site](http://davidwolff.dk/projects/learning/School%20Projects/Portfolio3-MMD/index.html), and press the link "About", the bottom of the tab that shows up.

It behaves differently in Chrome than in IE and Firefox.
In IE and Firefox, the text at the bottom of the tab gets cut off, while it doesn't in Chrome.

I have tried to use the development tools in all 3 browsers, and tried to locate the problem, but I can't.
I hope some of you could help me locate it.

I didn't include a jsFiddle, as I'm not sure wherein the problem lies.

Comment: Why the downvotes? What about the question isn't valid, even though it's a big question?

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not all browsers utilize the same rendering engine or follow the same rules. This is why they all look different in your case. The Opera browser actually adheres to the HTML guidelines the best. Unfortunately, they wont always all render the same and it's a constant issue for developers. I would use strict CSS as much as possible as browsers tend to follow stricter CSS rules better.

Hope this helped. Good luck.

Comment: "*The Opera browser actually adheres to the HTML guidelines the best*". According to what criteria?

Comment: @Oriol By W3C standards, the Opera browser is the most compliant. And was that really worth the downvote? lol...if anything, i think my answer deserved an upvote. I gave an explanation as to why OP is having this issue and also advice to help OP fix his issue.

Comment: The Opera browser also shows how I should ahve designed my site, according to chrome. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has a slightly different native styling system that you have to be careful of.

For example, Firefox uses "gecko:"

> The -moz-appearance CSS property is used in Gecko (Firefox) to display an element using a platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme.

So Firefox uses Gecko, Chrome uses Webkit, and IE uses their own system. Each one is slightly different, and you have to account for that in your css.

I would try to stick to regular css and use browser specific css when trying to accomplish a more complicated CSS3 style like [transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Comment: I did use brower specific prefix, if that's what you mean? But I understand what you say, Maybe I have to be more specific with my CSS in the future.

Comment: In the future, you should include the relevant css and html in your question, so it can be more easily viewed. I'll take a look at it one more time though.

Comment: Just tried to copy/paste it all into jsfiddle. The problem didn't accur. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you have done this because I cannot view your CSS file, but having a **CSS reset** style in the CSS file is good practice. You could achieve this by resetting all the basic rules like **margin, padding, border, font-size, font, vertical-align**, and **display** to their default values like **0**, **block**, **inherit**, and **100%**.  You can use the * (asterisk) to style all tags or list them all out individually separated by commas.  The reason to do this is because each browser comes with their own set styles in place by default, which may override your own styles and cause unwanted interference within your site. This is good practice to do.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I have included a css reset in my html file, above my custom stylesheet. So all the values should be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your .target class position value and see what changes are happening.  Also try adding in the respective margin values.  What is happening is that your footer has a higher z-index then your body, which is making it want to cover up whatever overflows onto it.